How to check some yum configuration variables in RHEL 5
We could use the yum-config-manager to check the yum configuration variables in RHEL 6 and higher ...
But in RHEL 5, there was no the yum-config-manager program, and also neither the yum-debug-dump nor the python could realize such function.

Here just for an example with RHEL 6: 
# 
# yum-config-manager  main|grep -Ei "metadata|keep"
keepalive = True
keepcache = False
metadata_expire = 21600
# 


why not simply directly work with the configuration files in /etc? What did yum-config-manager do for you that simple grep itself couldn't do? I ask because in your use case, grep Ei "metadata|keep" /etc/yum.conf would have done the same, with no real need for yum-config-manager to begin with. But maybe you're planning to do more advanced stuff – which I can't know.

Why are you still doing new development on an OS that's been EOL for over 7 years?

We still have a few older production systems running with older version of the DB/APPs ...
We highly think that the yum variable values might also be "hidden" somewhere else in the running kernel,  but we have not yet found them ...

Due to the yum program itself based python, we should still use the python to check the yum variables.

# 
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.metadata_expire, width=1)'  
3600
# 
# 
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.mirrorlist_expire, width=1)'  
86400
# 
# 
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.reposdir, width=1)'  
['/etc/yum/repos.d',
 '/etc/yum.repos.d']
# 


Or you might also use the following method to get all the yum variables values.
Note: but they would be output without their corresponding yum variables names.

# 
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.__dict__, width=1)'  |wc -l
109
# 

